# Keyerror when doing a json post request on sqlalchemy

Tags: json, ajax, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am working on a project for class where I have to edit starter Code. I keep getting a KeyError code and I am not sure what the issue is.

> line 250, in create_venue_submission
> name = request.get_json()['name']
> KeyError: 'name'

Code Below from new_venue.html

I added id="name", city, etc.. for all the divs . I'm not sure if that is the correct way to do it but thats the only way i figured to pull all the data from the form.

```
   {% extends 'layouts/main.html' %}
{% block title %}New Venue{% endblock %}
{% block content %}
  <div class="form-wrapper">
    <form id="venueInfo" method="post" class="form">
      <h3 class="form-heading">List a new venue <a href="{{ url_for('index') }}" title="Back to homepage"><i class="fa fa-home pull-right"></i></a></h3>
      <div id='name' class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        {{ form.name(class_ = 'form-control', autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
          <label>City & State</label>
          <div class="form-inline">
            <div id='city' class="form-group">
              {{ form.city(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='City', autofocus = true) }}
            </div>
            <div id='state' class="form-group">
              {{ form.state(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='State', autofocus = true) }}
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div id='address' class="form-group">
        <label for="address">Address</label>
        {{ form.address(class_ = 'form-control', autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div id='phone_num' class="form-group">
          <label for="phone">Phone</label>
          {{ form.phone(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='xxx-xxx-xxxx', autofocus = true) }}
        </div>
      <div id="genres" class="form-group">
        <label for="genres">Genres</label>
        <small>Ctrl+Click to select multiple</small>
        {{ form.genres(class_ = 'form-control', autofocus = true) }}
      </div>
      <div id="fb_link" class="form-group">
          <label for="genres">Facebook Link</label>
          {{ form.facebook_link(class_ = 'form-control', placeholder='http://', autofocus = true) }}
        </div>
      <input type="submit" value="Create Venue" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">
    </form>

    <script type="text/javascript">

      document.getElementById("venueInfo").onsubmit=function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        fetch('/venues/create',{
        method:'POST',
        body:JSON.stringify({
          'name': document.getElementById('name').value,
          'city': document.getElementById('city').value,
          'state': document.getElementById('state').value,
          'address': document.getElementById('address').value,
          'phone_num': document.getElementById('phone_num').value,
          'genres': document.getElementById('genres').value,
          'fb_link': document.getElementById('fb_link').value,
      }),
        headers: {'Content-type': 'application/json'}
      })
      .then(function(){
      })
    }

    </script>


  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

Code below is from app.py

```
@app.route('/venues/create', methods=['GET'])
def create_venue_form():
  form = VenueForm()
  return render_template('forms/new_venue.html', form=form)

    @app.route('/venues/create', methods=['POST'])
def create_venue_submission():
  name = request.get_json()['name']
  print(name)

  flash('Venue ' + request.form['name'] + ' was successfully listed!')

  return render_template('pages/home.html')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you're using Flask-WTF to make those form fields, then using a JS function to grab the values from these with `getElementById`.

The problem is you don't set an `id` on the form fields.  To get a better visualization of this, have a look at the rendered HTML, rather than the template code itself.

So instead of:

```
{{ form.name(class_ = 'form-control', autofocus = true) }}
```

You're looking for someting like:

```
{{ form.name(id='name', class_ = 'form-control', autofocus = true) }}
```

Then verify that renders to something like:

```
<input autofocus class="form-control" id="name" name="name" type="text" value="">
```

Note this now has an `id` attribute, which should allow your JS function to grab the value.

You'll need to appy this same concept to the other form fields.

> I added id="name", city, etc.. for all the divs . I'm not sure if that is the correct way to do it but thats the only way i figured to pull all the data from the form.

Doing this for the `divs` is no use... `document.getElementById('name').value` takes the value of an input field, so that's what you'd have to add the `id` attribute to, as above.

**EDIT regarding comment**

In your `create_venue_submission` route, the `request.get_json` method receives the values submitted by the javascript Fetch request. On the other hand, `request.form` contains the values if the form is submitted without Javascript.

With the Javascript method: `e.preventDefault()` prevents that traditional form submission when the button is clicked, and instead submits the Fetch request, with the header `{'Content-type': 'application/json'}`.

Either by removing that script tag, or running in a browser with javascript disabled it will fall back to the traditional submission method.

So you should probably do some logic in your flask route to test this condition.  You can also use `request.is_json` boolean for this.  Remember to do `from flask import jsonify`.  Something like:

```
if request.is_json:

    # Request came in via javascript based on the header provided.

    name = request.get_json()['name']

    # Add data to database or something

    return jsonify({'message':f'{name} was sucessfully listed.'})

else:
    # handle traditional form submission
    
    name = request.form['name']
    
    # Add data to database or something

    flash('Venue ' + request.form['name'] + ' was successfully listed!')
    return render_template('pages/home.html')
```

Of course you'll then need to [handle the returned JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch) in your frontend.  So insead of:

```
.then(function(){
      })
```

Something like:

```
.then(response => response.json())
.then(data => {
    console.log(data);
});
```

Now with the browser's dev tools Console open you should see something like this when submitted:

```
Object { message: "Burning Man Festival was sucessfully listed." }
```

Of course you could then swap that `console.log` line out with anything to manipulate the dom, and access for example `data['message']` to get the success string itself.

Comment: Thank you, that worked!  for some reason tho once I did that something else happens.      {flash('Venue ' + request.form['name'] + ' was successfully listed!')
 return render_template('pages/home.html')} doesnt do anything. meaning if I remove the script part from the .html the page normally goes to a home page and says venue x has been created. but once I have the script for the fetch nothing happens when I click create venue.